# php tmp name file not showing in xampp/tmp folder

Tags: php

It may be a silly question, But I have this question from many days.

If I just echo file temporary name

```
$tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name];
echo $tmp;
```

After upload an image I geted tmp directory like this

```
C:\xampp\tmp\php3489.tmp
```

Manually I checked there are no any file with name php3489 in c:\xampp\tmp. If there are no any file why php showing this name in echo ?

Comment: The file is deleted automatically when the script is finished. If you want to keep the file you have to move it somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is deleted automatically when the script is finished.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> Files will, by default be stored in the server's default temporary directory, unless another location has been given with the upload_tmp_dir directive inphp.ini.

Later:

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

If you want to keep the file you have to move it somewhere else, usually with the function [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Answer (score -2):

I found the problem it's just that it sticks a randomly generated name to the tmp_name's img name like:- F:\Xampp\tmp\rendome name.tmp
We just have to change that random name to the original name of that img like :-F:\Xampp\tmp\origanl img name.png or anything
And it works

Comment: You don't temper with temporary files. That's why they have random names. You must move that file to proper non-temp dir with original name.